# finding last occurrence using boost string

Tags: c++, string, boost

How can I obtain similar functionality with boost

```
  int idx = md.filepath.lastIndexOf('/');                                 
      md.title = md.filepath.right(md.filepath.length() - idx -1);            
      md.title = md.title.left(md.title.length() - 4);
```

Above code( QT based) finds the name of the file without extension , md is an object , filepath, title are  QString . I have browsed boost's string methods like find_last but it returns iterator_range. I m new to boost , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is filename parsing then you'd be better off using the [`boost::filesystem::path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#class-path) class. In particular the following methods:

[`path  filename() const;`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-filename)

[`path  stem() const;`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-stem) and

[`path  extension() const;`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-extension)

The class provides conversions to and from `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

Comment: thanks for replying . I was looking for a way to get the filename without its extension . eg Filepath : /home/user/file.ext . I just want 'file' not 'file.ext'

Comment: That is what the `stem` function provides you with.